# Regex with place holder

Tags: javascript

```
var scale = $('#'+fields[i].id+'-scale').val();
var decimalOnly = '/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\,\d{1,'+scale+'})?\s*$/';
    if(fields[i].value != "" && !(fields[i].value).match(decimalOnly)) {
        $(fields[i]).addClass('form-attr-error');
            result = false;
    }
    else {
        $(fields[i]).removeClass('form-attr-error');
    }
```

In the above RegEx passing the 'scale' placeholder value & comparing `value.match(RegEx)` it's not working.

But it as working like this

```
value.match(/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\,\d{1,2})?\s*$/);
```

please help me on this how can i pass place holder value in place of '2'.

Answer (score 0):

`.match` will automatically convert a string argument into a regexp; if you want to be explicit about it, you can use the `RegExp` constructor. But note that slashes are not part of the regexp, they are part of the regexp *literal*. I.e. these will do the same thing:

```
foo.match(/a/)
foo.match("a")
foo.match(new RegExp("a"))
```

These will all do the same thing that is *different* from the first set:

```
foo.match(/\/a\/)
foo.match("/a/")
foo.match(new RegExp("/a/"))
```

The former ones will match one-letter sequence `a`; the latter ones will match the three-letter sequence `/a/`.

tl;dr: get rid of slashes in `decimalOnly`.